# Extract dates, of variable structure, from a series of filenames and add to the source rasters as a date variable (R)

Tags: r, date, raster, gsub

I have a large series of rasters, constituting a timeseries of climate data (1 layer / month) from which I am ultimately aiming to extract values at a series of coordinates. I have imported them, into RStudio, from the file as a list, and then stacked them:

```
Temp_list <- list.files('C:/Users/xxxx/Desktop/Project/climate_data/temp', full.names = TRUE) 
TempST <-  stack(Temp_list)
```

There are >600 layer and they are named in the structure:

CLIMATdata_temp_1_1988_V.1.5

CLIMATdata_temp_12_2001_V.1.5

i.e Month is listed after the variable type (here temp) and before year.
The problem I encounter is that months before October are listed as single digits (without a 0 beforehand) while months after October are listed as 2 digits.

I want to loop through each layer and extract the month and year from the filename, to then convert this to date format.

I wish to obtain '*1_1988*' and '*12_2001*' from the above file names, and then convert these to date objects.

I understand I need to use regular expressions to do so,  but don't fully understand the structure and I am struggling with the discrepancy in the number of digits. I have tried the below code, but haven't had any success:

```
for (i in TempST) {
  Dt <- sub(pattern = '.*temp_(\d+\_\d+).*', i) #also '^(?:.*_)?([0-9]{1:2})([0-9]{4})(?:\..*)?$'
  YrMo <- as.Date(dt, '%m_%Y')
  i <- setZ(i, ym, 'date')
  names(i) <- Dt
}
```

I'm sure this is a fairly simple fix, but I have struggled with it for a while now. Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: Please share the pattern  you tried.

Comment: I've added a couple of my attempts, but they yield the error '\x is an unrecognized escape in character string...'.

Comment: That would be very helpful in fact. Note you just need to double the backslashes. Also, since you captured the substring and matched all the string, when using `sub`, you simply need to use a backreference to get just the captured value. Try `sub('.*temp_(\\d+_\\d+).*', '\\1', i)`

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is about sorting strings with numbers in them, and treat these as numbers rather than alphabetically. And then extracting parts of the name and make a date (the question is not related to rasters). Also note that, no matter how you do it, you can and should do this on the entire vector, not in a loop.

Example data

```
f <- sort(paste0("a_2010_", 1:12, "_b.tif"))
f <- c(f, gsub(2010, 2011, f))
```

Use stringr::str_sort

```
library(stringr)
ff <- str_sort(f, numeric=TRUE)
```

Or roll your own:

```
x <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(basename(f), "_")))
x[,2] <- as.numeric(x[,2])
x[,3] <- as.numeric(x[,3])
i <- order(x[,2], x[,3])
ff <- f[i]

ff
# [1] "a_2010_1_b.tif"  "a_2010_2_b.tif"  "a_2010_3_b.tif"  "a_2010_4_b.tif" 
# [5] "a_2010_5_b.tif"  "a_2010_6_b.tif"  "a_2010_7_b.tif"  "a_2010_8_b.tif" 
# [9] "a_2010_9_b.tif"  "a_2010_10_b.tif" "a_2010_11_b.tif" "a_2010_12_b.tif"
#[13] "a_2011_1_b.tif"  "a_2011_2_b.tif"  "a_2011_3_b.tif"  "a_2011_4_b.tif" 
#[17] "a_2011_5_b.tif"  "a_2011_6_b.tif"  "a_2011_7_b.tif"  "a_2011_8_b.tif" 
#[21] "a_2011_9_b.tif"  "a_2011_10_b.tif" "a_2011_11_b.tif" "a_2011_12_b.tif"
```

To get the dates:

```
ff <- str_sort(f, numeric=TRUE)
x <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(basename(ff), "_")))
dates <- apply(cbind(x[,2:3], 15), 1, function(i) paste(i, collapse="-"))
d <- as.Date(dates) 

d
# [1] "2010-01-15" "2010-02-15" "2010-03-15" "2010-04-15" "2010-05-15"
# [6] "2010-06-15" "2010-07-15" "2010-08-15" "2010-09-15" "2010-10-15"
#[11] "2010-11-15" "2010-12-15" "2011-01-15" "2011-02-15" "2011-03-15"
#[16] "2011-04-15" "2011-05-15" "2011-06-15" "2011-07-15" "2011-08-15"
#[21] "2011-09-15" "2011-10-15" "2011-11-15" "2011-12-15"
```

or, remove what you do not want from the filenames (and once you have the dates it is easy to sort, so you do not need to pre-sort)

```
xf <- gsub("a_", "", f)
xf <- gsub("_b.tif", "", xf)
dd <- as.Date(paste0(xf, "_15"), "%Y_%m_%d")
i <- order(dd)
ff <- ff[i]
dd <- dd[i]
```

or if you actually do not care about the order, and you know what years you have, you can do

```
years <- 2010:2011
d <- paste0(rep(years,each=12), "-", rep(c(1,10:12,2:9), length(years)), "-", 15) 
as.Date(d)
```

regex is a bit tricky, but here is an approach that partly uses it

```
g <- gsub("[^[:digit:]]", "", f)
as.Date(paste0(substr(g, 1, 4), "-", substr(g, 5, 7), "-", 15))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the issue using

```r
sub('.*temp_(\\d+_\\d+).*', '\\1', i)
```

Here,

- `.*temp_` matches any zero or more chars, as many as possible and then `temp_` string
- `(\d+_\d+)`  captures into Group 1 any one or more digits, `_` and then any one or more digits
- `.*` - any zero or more chars, as many as possible.

The `\1` replacement keeps just the Group 1 value in the result.

Comment: Thank you for the full explanation. This definitely seems like it should extract the piece I want, but when I apply the code it returns the metadata of the raster layer (i.e. ncol, nrow, extent etc.). Maybe I have mistakenly described my data wrong, the file names I refer to are listed under 'names' in the raster layers.